# How to create dynamic web application without eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

All tutorials i see on creating dynamic web application are using eclipse IDE. I want to try to make a web application skeleton without eclipse's help because i don't want to be dependent on it. I want to understand it fully without any automatically generated files by eclipse.

So are there tutorials out there you can share with me?

Comment: Start from here...[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! However, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you @darshanpatel ! i will learn this. and honk, im sorry for that i misunderstood the guidelines for asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a standard folder structure for java web application as shown below.

`/META-INF
           Standard jar stuff like manifest.xml
        /WEB-INF
           web.xml
           /classes
             /com...etc.
           /lib`

after which you create a .war file using ant tool and deploy it in the application server.